# creating admin folder inside CodeIgniter App

Tags: codeigniter

I have the front end fully working in a codeIgniter application. Now, I have to create admin as well. So, How would I create the admin section creating a new directory. Without interrupting codeigniter directory structure.

```
localhost/myapp/admin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter already supports 1 subfolder level within the controllers folder. So within /applications/controllers/ you can just add /applications/controllers/admin/ and it will work fine.

Comment: This is correct. However one word of warning the default app will be the same for the admin folder, so if you ever run into a problem such as when "forums.php" is your default folder for the root, domain.com/admin will call controllers/admin/forums.php as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could omit it out via .htaccess so that the directory actually works like a directory rather than how its initially developed to work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

what this does is turn on apache modrewrite then tells apache any calls to index.php, robots.txt or yourdomain.com/admin/ (and any sub-folders/files within) treat as you would normally without codeigniter mucking up the works. Also this will remove the required index.php from the URL you will be able to link to your site like

mydomain.com/home/
instead of mydomain.com/index.php/home/

Comment: Not at all. I want such directory where I can create its own controllers, views and models.

Comment: are you looking to have multiple codeigniter installs? or you want to use this admin within the same CI install you currently have? Cause based on your initial question I gathered you wanted the admin directory to be independent of the CI install all together. If you want admin to be in the same install then its as simple as creating a new controller and view for "admin"

Answer (score 0):

There's an explanation about that in [CI User Guide: Managing your Applications](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html)